# Autodesk Forge upload results in 504 gateway timeout

Tags: php, http, forge

We are trying to upload a file via forge ObjectsApi in php. This results in http 504 gateway timeout all the time. The file is 800kb, so this shouldn't be an issue.

This is the code:

```
$twoLeggedAuth = new Autodesk\Auth\OAuth2\TwoLeggedAuth();
$twoLeggedAuth->setScopes( [ 'data:write' ] );

$twoLeggedAuth->fetchToken();

$apiInstance = new Autodesk\Forge\Client\Api\ObjectsApi( $twoLeggedAuth );
$filename = $inputFileName;
$body = $filename;
$file = new SplFileObject( $body );
$content_length = $file->getSize();  
$object_name = $file->getFilename(); 

try {
 $result = $apiInstance->uploadObject( $bucket_key, $object_name, $content_length, $body, null, null );
} catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo 'Exception when calling ObjectsApi->uploadObject: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which results in

```
Exception when calling ObjectsApi->uploadObject: [504] Error connecting to the API (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/bobbie_pat/objects/test.dwg)
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation states that the code is buggy 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/basic-usage-forge-sdk-php has a fix:

> But there is an issue on the uploadObject method, we will face an error 504. To fix this issue, there is a workaround to change line #196 of the forge-php-client/lib/ApiClient.php.
>
> ```
> //From:
> curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData );
>
> //To:
> curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents( $postData ) );
> ```

No clue why they don't just fix their SDK instead of posting a fix on their own website.

Comment: You could raise a PR [on this file](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-php-client/blob/82232ba6309fb52c2bd506e65aeac51929ebed26/lib/ApiClient.php#L196), but if they're not accepting changes, you could just create a fork and pull that instead.

Comment: Ah, [here's the reason](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-php-client/issues/10#issuecomment-355813327) - they are not maintaining the SDK any more. However, they say they will accept a PR, so it just needs someone to do it!